# Workflow doesn't fire when new item is created through Event receiver

Tags: workflow, event-receivers

When new item is added through event receiver in a list, I have OOTB workflow on item created on that list. But unfortunately it doesn't works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you share the code you were using for triggering the OOTB wf? If its sp 2013 workflow / WF manager, you need to use that specific API to call that method. In 2010 /2007 spworkflowmanager class need to be used for triggering the WF with  GUID and name.

Comment: I have SPD workflow and the new entry is created programatically(through event receiver) in the list.But when I manually add the record, the SPD workflow runs successfully. But it doesnt seems to work whem item is added programatically(through Event recceiver)

Comment: didn't get the point. why you want to add an item in splist through itemeventreceiver? you can write the code in the visual web part which web part or a content editor /script editor web part to insert the item. then only the eventreceiver fires, if i am not wrong. can elaborate your use case a little bit more.

Comment: Its the requirement so compulsorily i have to use Event receiver to add the new item in the list.

Comment: Can you add the event receiver item add code? Are you using `item.SystemUpdate();`?